# Создание List в Spring

Tags: java, spring, исключения, list

Выдает большой кусок текста об ошибке, но не могу понять в чем дело

XML файл:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <util:list id="cities">
            <bean class="com.example.java.test.City">
                <property name="name" value="Chicago"/>
                <property name="state" value="IL"/>
                <property name="population" value="2853114"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.example.java.test.City">
                <property name="name" value="Atlanta"/>
                <property name="state" value="GA"/>
                <property name="population" value="537958"/>
            </bean>
        </util:list>

    </beans>
```

Class:

```
public class City {

    private String name;
    private String state;
    private int population;

    public City() {

    }

    public City(String name, String state, int population) {
        this.name = name;
        this.state = state;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main"
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>  Line 9 in XML document from class path resource
>  [Application_Context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 32;
>  cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>  declaration can be found for element 'util:list'.  at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:252)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>  org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at com.example.java.test.Main.main(Main.java:10) Caused by:
>  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 32;
>  cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no
>  declaration can be found for element 'util:list'.  at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:395)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:326)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:283)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:510)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3587)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2142)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:828)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2706)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:531)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:885)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:821)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
>     at
>  java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
>     at
>  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
>     ... 14 more
> ```

если убрать этот `List`, то всё работает без проблем, понятно что дело в нем, но что именно происходит не понимаю.
Только что заметил,что при использовании:

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

появляется похожее сообщение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке сказано, что определение элемента `util:list` не найдено:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no can be found for element 'util:list'.

Выдаёт эту ошибку парсер XML и скорее всего ему нужно указать расположение схемы, поэтому попробуйте добавить расположение схемы(`http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd`) в атрибут `xsi:schemaLocation`  - 
в теге `<beans ...>`

В итоге тег beans, будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">
```

Comment: я пробовал вводить xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" потому что IDE сама подсказала,но на счет последних двух и намека не давала,теперь всё работает(после добавления последних двух строк),спасибо!